# Jenkins File - Execute shell command in active choice script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, pipeline, jenkins-groovy

everyone, I'm using plugin "[Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/)" in my Jenkins, I try to do something condition, and the return based on environment host that will be executed in shell command in my Jenkins file. the command like "echo ${BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}, echo ${BUILD_VERSION}..etc".

Already doing this but the list is still empty. now, what do I have to do to make this work? thank you.

JenkinsFile:

```
properties([
        parameters([
            [$class: 'ChoiceParameter',
             choiceType: 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                    name: 'ENVIRONMENT',
                    description: 'Select Environment',
                    script: [
                            $class: 'GroovyScript',
                            script: [
                                    classpath: [],
                                    sandbox: true,
                                    script: '''
                                    def getEnvVar(String name) {
                                        return sh(script: "echo \${$name}", returnStdout: true).trim()
                                    }
                                    def env = getEnvVar("ENVIRONMENT")
                                    if (envs != "testing") {
                                        return ["stage", "dev", "prod"]
                                    }else{
                                        return ["testing"]
                                    }
                                    ''',
                            ],
                            ]

                    ]
    ])
])
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Your script returns the output of bash command `echo ${ENVIRONMENT}` which is supposedly empty.

Comment: thanks for the information, so if the output empty will it be on the else block and return array ["testing"]?

btw im already set the env host with `export INVIRONMENT=xxx`

Answer (score 0):

im fix it with another solution, but maybe isnt the best option.

1st create a method to load the env file (i set the values on it), then define to jenkins global variable.

```
getEnvHosts = { ->
    node {
        script {
            // Get the environment hosts file
            def props = readProperties file: '/var/lib/jenkins/env/dast-service-env'

            //define to jenkins global variable
            env.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT = props['BUILD_ENVIRONMENT']
        }
    }

}
```

and then i call the "BUILD_ENVIRONMENT" with `${env.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}` like this in active choice parameter:

```
getEnvHosts()
properties([
        parameters([
                [$class     : 'ChoiceParameter',
                 choiceType : 'PT_SINGLE_SELECT',
                 name       : 'BUILD_ENVIRONMENT',
                 description: "Select Environment default is ${env.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}",
                 script     : [
                         $class: 'GroovyScript',
                         script: [
                                 classpath: [],
                                 sandbox  : true,
                                 script   : """
                                        def envs = "${env.BUILD_ENVIRONMENT}"
                                            if (envs == "stage") {
                                                choices = ["stage", "dev", "prod", "testing"]
                                            }else if (envs == "dev") {
                                                choices = ["dev", "prod", "stage", "testing"]
                                            }else if (envs == "prod") {
                                                choices = ["prod", "dev", "stage", "testing"]
                                            }else{
                                                choices = ["testing", "stage", "dev", "prod"]
                                            }
                                        return choices
                                        """,
                         ],
                 ]
                ],
        ])
])
```